# How do I obtain the SPWorkflow object in the event receiver?

Tags: workflow, event-handlers, object-model

I have a [workflow event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventreceiver.aspx) which is handling the `WorkflowStarted` and `WorkflowCompleted` events. I need to obtain references to the workflow list item and the workflow object to do some additional processing. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mihai,

You can have a look at [this question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/75304724-f32f-466b-90d4-f4fdfe7f2bf7) which will give you code reference to get the workflow association with Workflow Manager

And here is how you can get the item, history, tasks etc:

```
  public override void WorkflowStarted(SPWorkflowEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.WorkflowStarted(properties);

       SPSite site = new SPSite("SPURL");
       SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
       SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
       SPWorkflowCollection workflowCollection = new SPWorkflowCollection(list);
       SPListItem item = null;
       SPList task = null;
       SPList history = null;
       foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in workflowCollection)
       {
           if (workflow.InstanceId == properties.InstanceId)
           {
               item = list.GetItemById(workflow.ItemId);
               task = workflow.TaskList;
               history = workflow.HistoryList;

           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SPWorkflowEventProperties` class object like

`properties.ActivationProperties.Workflow` to get the reference of workflow.

`properties.ActivationProperties.List` to get the reference of list. And

`properties.ActivationProperties.Item` to get the reference of Item.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the *right* way to do it, and with much less code than the other answer.